# C++ Error: Continue option is not working and is looping the program instead

Tags: c++, debugging

Note: I am a beginner in C++, so please bear with me if there are any serious programming errors that can be fixed easily.

Edit: Options 3 and 4 work perfectly fine without any errors. However, Option 2 has a serious looping problem where 'Error! Number should be in range of (1 to 100)' and 'Enter the number again:' loop continuously when you input any key. Will change the code to show the code for Option 2 and remove Option 3 and Option 4's code.

I created a math program that can calculate numbers, calculate fractions, among other features I added. I added a continue button on some programs (Option 2) that when you enter 'Y' on your keyboard, it should loop the program until the user types a different key to signify that the program should stop. However, the continue button seems not to work. When I press any other key, the program still loops and I have to stop the program so it cannot loop.

```
#include <<iostream>>
#include <<cmath>>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Math Application Version 0.1 (currently in development)\n";
  std::cout << "Choose an application to use (use numbers 1 - 10)\n":
  std::cout << "Option 1: Calculator" << std::endl "Option 2: Use Average Calculator" << 
  std::endl << "Option 3: Use Fraction Calculator\n" << std::endl << 
  "Option 4: Use LCM (Lowest Common Denominator) Calculator\n";
   int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
   switch (choice)
   {
     case 1:
  // this is blank on purpose because this would get too long if I added more features here
 case 2:
{
printf("\n Chose average calculator.");
char d;
int n, i;
float num[100], 
sum=0.0, 
average;
anon:
{
cout << "Enter the numbers of data (limit is 100) : ";
cin >> n;

while (n > 100 || n <= 0)
{
    cout << "Error! Number should be in range of (1 to 100)." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number again: ";
    cin >> n;
}

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
    cin >> num[i];
    sum += num[i];
}

average = sum / n;
cout << "Average = " << average;
}
cout << "\nDo you want to continue? "; cin >> n;
  if (n== 'Y', "Yes")
  goto anon;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
break;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this issue or a detailed explanation since this is very confusing for me.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but you just have some typos in these lines.

```
cout << "\nDo you want to continue? ";
cin >> n;
/*Here => */ if (n== 'Y', "Yes")
```

fix it to `if(n == 'Y')`, also you have unintentionally used `n` instead of the `char d` that you have defined to use as a check.

So your code should be

```
cout << "\nDo you want to continue? ";
cin >> d;
if (d == 'Y') { .... }
```

And for completion, avoid `goto` whenever you can. You can use a `while` loop instead of the assembly-like `goto`.

This is your code but with a `while` loop instead of `goto`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Math Application Version 0.1 (currently in development)\n";
    std::cout << "Choose an application to use (use numbers 1 - 10)\n";
    std::cout << "Option 1: Calculator" << std::endl << "Option 2: Use Average Calculator" << 
        std::endl << "Option 3: Use Fraction Calculator\n" << std::endl << 
        "Option 4: Use LCM (Lowest Common Denominator) Calculator\n";
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            // this is blank on purpose because this would get too long if I added more features here
        case 2:
            printf("\n Chose average calculator.");
            char d = 'Y';
            int n, i;
            float num[100],
                  sum=0.0,
                  average;
            while (d == 'Y'){
                cout << "Enter the numbers of data (limit is 100) : ";
                cin >> n;

                while (n > 100 || n <= 0)
                {
                    cout << "Error! Number should be in range of (1 to 100)." << endl;
                    cout << "Enter the number again: ";
                    cin >> n;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number: ";
                    cin >> num[i];
                    sum += num[i];
                }

                average = sum / n;
                cout << "Average = " << average;
                cout << "\nDo you want to continue? ";
                cin >> d;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```